# Load .php page and fill input with form action

Tags: javascript, php

I have a page with a live search function called "list.php". On another page, I have a search input, and upon submit of that search, I'd like to take the query, load list.php and fill the live search on list.php.

list.php has the following:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="databaseSearch()" placeholder="Search">
```

And my other page's search is:

```
 <form action="search2.php">
 <input class="mb0" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
 </form>
```

I would think the best way to do this would be with a form action, but I'm not sure how to both load list.php AND fill in #myInput

Thanks!

Comment: Would you like to write it in Jquery? or a Must Javascript?

Comment: I'm fine with either, whichever is more efficient

Comment: Put a form on search page and on form submit catch the details on list.php , execute the query and display the result . Or put the search fields and list on the same page and on submit create a session variable and hold the search values in an array in that variable and execute the SQL query after exploding the array and display the search result on the same page using JQuery .

Answer (score 0):

do something like that and change what suites your script, also do not forget using proper filters :
this on list.php and make the other form action points to list.php too:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['another_page_txt'])):  ?>
<script>
    $('#myInput').val('<?php print $_POST['another_page_txt']?>');
    $('#myInput').trigger('keyup');
</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing Value in the Function would get the text typed through, and using `.val()` means you wish to put the value gotten into any form field required there is `value=""` option

This is a script pointing to Jquery CDN file online

`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

If you have Jquery You Prolly won't need this

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="databaseSearch(value)" placeholder="Search">

  <form action="search2.php">
    <input class="mb0" type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
  </form>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     function databaseSearch(value) {
        $(".mb0").val(value);
     }
  </script>
```

Important Additions are

```
onkeyup="databaseSearch(value)"
```

And

```
function databaseSearch(value) {
   $(".mb0").val(value);
}
```

Good Luck :)